# How to get the facebook friends list in developer api2.4

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As I have searched many thing to get the friends count using script or php. But i could't get the actual result.
Most of the result will shows these thing only.

**As of Tuesday 22nd July 2014, we now return a total_count field within a summary property in the response to /v2.2/me/friends.**

But i dono how to get the friends count. Kindly help me I wasted whole day to get this.

I have tried the following code to get my friends count

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'My app Id',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.4' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the `FB.api('/me', function(response) {` it will return my user id and name, I have tried with `FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {` it returns an empty array..

Please help me out from this..

Answer (score 2):

For getting the list of friends from version 2+ FB has added an extra permission `user_friends` that you must ask the user to access his friend list. From your code above it seems you don't have the permission.Add `user_friends` to the scope parameter.

So your login button parameter should be like this

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_friends" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

Hint: You can use the following URL to check that you have that permission or not.

```
GET /{user-id}/permissions
```

If you have the permission already and you are getting an empty response because from version 2+ `/me/friends` returns the user's friends who are also using your app, and if your app is relatively new none of your friends might be using the application.

You might want to read the [upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids) from Facebook to get better insight about it.

Comment: can you please explain `GET /{user-id}/permissions ` with sample code.From my code

Comment: in your `testAPI()` you can retrive the user id and then make a GET call to the above mentioned URL, You should have the permission `user_friends` in the returned array to get the friend count